# Linking Two Tables to Generate Report in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am building a school management system as my final project and within that I want to provide facility for checking attendance of students. In the student table, I have

```
(StudID, Name, ClassID, Address,D.O.B, etc)
```

in the attendance table, I have

```
(DayID, ClassID, Date,DayPresent and DayAbsent)
```

and in Class Table I have

```
(ClassID, ClassName, ClassActive).
```

My worry is how to link the student table to attendance table so that reports can be generated on the number of times a student attends school within a particular period.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM studentTable as [student] 
 INNER JOIN attendanceTable as [attendance] 
 ON attendance.ClassID=student.ClassID
INNER JOIN classTable as [class]
 ON class.ClassID = attendance.ClassID
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to do a table join.

the easy way to do it would be like this

```
select A.StudID,
B.DayAbsent
from [database].dbo.[studentTable] A 
inner join
[database2name].dbo.[AttendanceTable] B
on
A.ClassID= B.ClassID
```

in short, the select, selects the rows from either table you want,

and the `A.ClassID= B.ClassID` is the two items you want to match

Comment: this also brings an entire report back for all the students and their days absent